# programmatically switch to tab in Google Chrome, and open URL if tab not found

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd need the following functionality for Google Chrome. 
I didn't find a command line parameter that could help me here.

- check if a URL is open in one of the Google Chrome tabs
- if so, activate this tab
- if not, open the URL in a new tab

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I don't think you'll get access to this via JavaScript or similar due to this violating the end-users security.  You'll need to build a browser extension/addon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [Chrome extensions docs - Tabs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) will help you!

Just to make it clear you can't NOT access anything beyond your Domain in JavaScript because of [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, triggering an alert can have the desired effect. Run this code in your console in one tab and switch to another tab in the same browser.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert("Switched tabs");
}, 
5000);
```

The alert appearing after the timeout will trigger tab switch. Or you can do something similar! This should however be used if absolutely necessary to move user from current tab, like Google Calendar does.

**Update 2019**

With new versions of Chrome, this **no longer works**. As pointed out in the comment below, Chrome now shows a small icon in the tab to show a window/alert has been  triggered

Comment: I know this is an old answer.  But I just tried it now 2019 and it doesnt cause a switch of tab in the latest chrome version.  It just adds a small notification icon to the tab that the script is running in, without opening it up.

Comment: @user3094826 thanks for the heads up. I noticed the same a while back, I'll have to edit my answer to reflect this